# Android ListFragment @id attribute

Tags: android, android-listfragment

I place two ListFragment in my MainActivity.

This is the ListFragment xml file: fragment1.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@id/android:list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:drawSelectorOnTop="false" />

</LinearLayout>
```

My question is, why must I use android:id="@id/android:list" here? When I use, e.g., @+id/frag_list, the program crashes with Error "inflating class fragment".

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListActivity.html. same for listfragment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ListActivity has a default layout that consists of a single, full-screen list in the center of the screen. However, if you desire, you can customize the screen layout by setting your own view layout with `setContentView()` in `onCreate()`. To do this, your own view **MUST** contain a ListView object with the id `"@android:id/list"` (or list if it's in code). Its same when your class extends `ListFragment`.

For more info do check the docs

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListActivity.html.

You can extend Fragment instead of ListFragment. Have a custom layout with ListView. Then you can provide any id for your listview.